# How to close the window when clicked and open the new window

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search Again" onclick="return window.open('/apex/customreport');window.top.close();" />
```

it is opening one new window and the old window is also there .

when the button is clicked it has to close the current window and open the new window which i wrote above .answer would be great helpful

Comment: why would you want it?  why not just update the current window link/URL?  Can you detail more on the reason/logic that this is needed in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace "window.top.close()" with just "window.close()". It should work with IE & Chrome.

window.close() - is JavaScript function to close current window. But it's implementation is browser specific. It may not in Firefox if window is not created by JavaScript itself.

Comment: yeah javascript is only supposed to be allowed to close windows opened by javascript. It is able to do it even if they weren't in some browsers but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the name on both windows.  If they share the same name, then when you open one with the same name it will replace it.

```
apex:commandButton value="Search Again" onclick="window.open('/apex/customreport', 'myexample');" />
```